# MySQL combine 2 different counts in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table, that pretty much looks like this:
`users (id INT, masterId INT, date DATETIME)`

Every user has exactly one master. But masters can have n users.

Now I want to find out how many users each master has. I'm doing that this way:

```
SELECT `masterId`, COUNT(`id`) AS `total` FROM `users` GROUP BY `masterId` ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

But now I also want to know how many new users a master has since the last 14 days. I could do it with this query:

```
SELECT `masterId`, COUNT(`id`) AS `last14days` FROM `users` WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) GROUP BY `masterId` ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Now the question: Could I somehow get this information with one query, instead of using 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do this by only counting rows for with the condition is true. In standard SQL this would be done using a case expression inside the aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
  masterId, 
  COUNT(id) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS last14days
FROM users 
GROUP BY masterId 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74858c/1)

Comment: This query shows the exact same values for total and last14days in each row

Comment: @pimeys I've updated the query so it should work now.